# How do you filter an Observable with form input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a component with this "countries$" variable:

```
  countries$!: Observable<Country[]>;
```

that I'm populating with [this data](https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all) in an "ngOnInit" like this:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.countries$ = this.apiService.getAllCountries();
  }
```

and I'm accessing this variable/Observable in the html template like this:

```
<div>
  <app-country-card *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" [country]="country"></app-country-card>
</div>
```

---

I want to include a search bar that filters the countries down to whatever is typed in.

I thought I could use the filter function inside a pipe like this:

```
  searchFilterCountries(searchTerm: string){
    this.countries$.pipe(filter((country: any) => country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())))
  }
```

and put the input in the html template like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="searchFilterCountries($event.target.value)"/>
```

so that the filter function would fire every time theres an input, narrowing down the list of countries on display.

---

This doesn't work however. I'm getting the typescript error:

> Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ngtsc(2339)

---

Then I found a "sample" of a working filtered list here on Material UI

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples (The FILTER one)

I attempted to implement this and came up with this code:

```
 export class HomeComponent {
      countries$!: Observable<Country[]>;
      myControl = new FormControl('');
      constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(){
        this.countries$ = this.apiService.getAllCountries();
      }
    
    
      private _filter(value: string): Observable<Country[]> {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    
        return this.countries$.pipe(filter(option => option.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))) <----ERROR #2
      }
    
    }
```

It doesn't work however. I think because the values are observables, not the data inside the observable.

I have squiggly lines showing a TS error under the under the "name" property in "option.name.common" saying:

**option.name.common TS error**

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Country[]'

If I do this instead though:

```
 option => option[0].name.common.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)))
```

the error goes away, but I wouldn't be able to search all the values if I did that.

---

Am I on the right track here? Am I using the right operators? How do I fix the TS errors? I'm new to angular and don't know all the operators available. If I use mergeMap/switchMap will that solve my problem? If I do fix the typescript errors would it even work? Or is my approach wrong?

Can somebody help me get this working?

Comment: Can you include your definition of a Country object here too so can see what kinds of properties you're trying to have it search over?  I think you are roughly on one track that could work, I think a pipe honestly might be an easier option to apply the filtering with the changing input.  The Error 1 is because the type your _filter function returns is Observable<Country[]> but needs to basically be a string array so when it's mapped back into this.filteredOptions it matches the expected data type there.

Comment: I'm populating the country$ variable with the contents of: [https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all](https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all)

Answer (score 1):

Example pipe

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from './country';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterList',
})
export class FilterListPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(countries: Country[]|null, searchText: string): Country[] {
    if(!countries) return []
    return countries.filter(country=>country.name.indexOf(searchText) != -1);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="controlsGroup">
  <input type="text" formControlName="searchInput"/>

  <div *ngFor="let country of countries | async | filterList:searchText">
    <div>Name: {{country.name}}</div>
    <div>Ranking: {{country.ranking}}</div>
    <div>Metric: {{country.metric}}</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Country } from './country';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'piper-example-app';
  searchText = ''

  controlsGroup: FormGroup

  constructor(public fb:FormBuilder){
    this.controlsGroup = fb.group({
      searchInput: new FormControl('')
    })

    this.controlsGroup.get('searchInput')?.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.searchText=value)
  }

  countries: Observable<Country[]> = of([{
    name: 'United States of America',
    ranking: 1,
    metric: 'burgers per capita'
  },
  {
    name: 'China',
    ranking: 9000,
    metric: 'power level lower bound'
  }])
}
```

Admittedly I'm doing a few things that are "dirty" here where filtering the incoming observable stream of arrays of countries might be a bit more efficient.  Also note you'd need to still expand the filter function to check all the properties (can use for(prop in obj) type loop to iterate over all properties to see if any of them matches the searchText or adjust the criteria as see fit.

Bit more of a complete example showing the filter part with different types of properties being filtered slightly differently:

filter-list.pipe.ts (alternative)

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from './country';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterList',
})
export class FilterListPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(countries: Country[]|null, searchText: string): Country[] {
    if(!countries) return []
    return countries.filter(country => {
      let foundMatch = false;
      let property: keyof typeof country
      for(property in country) {
        if(typeof country[property] === 'string') {
          if((country[property] as string).indexOf(searchText) != -1)
          foundMatch = true
        }else {
          if((country[property] as number) == parseInt(searchText))
          foundMatch = true
        }
      }
      return foundMatch
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand on your current code and suggest some changes like this:

```js
export class HomeComponent {
  allCountries: Country[] = [];
  countries$!: Observable<Country[]>;
  myControl = new FormControl('');
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService
      .getAllCountries()
      .subscribe((countries) => (this.allCountries = countries));

    this.countries$ = combineLatest({
      searchTerm: this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
      countries: this.apiService
        .getAllCountries()
        .pipe(tap((countries) => (this.allCountries = countries))),
    }).pipe(map(({ searchTerm }) => this._filter(searchTerm)));
  }

  private _filter(value: string | null): Country[] {
    if (value === null) {
      return this.allCountries;
    }
    const filterValue = value?.toLowerCase();

    return this.allCountries.filter((country) =>
      country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
}
```

So we're keeping the original country list in a separate variable, and we are using the form control's valueChange event to filter the countries that we need to display.

The template should look like this:

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="myControl" />

<div *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async">
  <div>Name: {{ country.name.common }}</div>>
</div>
```

Comment: Should the "searchTerm" part be in the ngOnInit? Isn't ngOnInit for executing commands on/before first render?  Will this code be able to actively filter out countries as you type into the search bar AFTER initial render is completed? Also, how do I incorporate the search bar here? Don't I need to create a function that passes in the "event.target.value" as the search term? And then have that function run every time someone types/the text input changes. Does this code do that? I don't see where the "search term" is coming from.

Comment: the `searchTerm` is just a name I gave to the actual value, that gets emitted by the `valueChanges` observable. Would you like me to also include template code to display the list of countries and to hook up the `myControl` FormControl to the input?

Comment: How do I get the filter operator working? How come this doesn't work? 
    `return this.countries$.pipe(
      map(country=>country),
      filter(country => country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)))`....I feel like there must be an easy way to accomplish this

Comment: There is, just try the code that I included. Don't you find it easy enough?

Comment: sure because I still don't know how to accomplish this even with your code. Is my code in the OP just wrong? There's no way to simply create a function that filters and attach that function to an "onChange" in the input html element?

Comment: The fact that we connected the `myControl` form control variable to the input inside the template using the `formControl` directive is enough. Everything else will just work. Make sure to have the `ReactiveFormsModule` imported in the module that exports your `HomeComponent`. My solution was inspired from the same thing that [you linked](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples). Scroll to the _Filter autocomplete_ section and check out the code there.

Comment: I just pushed the entire project to [GitHub](https://github.com/SenBoyer/fmentor-angular) and a sandbox is here (if it works for you. Doesn't work for me right now for some reason): [https://codesandbox.io/s/github/fmentor-angular](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/SenBoyer/fmentor-angular). I used your code exactly but it still doesn't work. Do you see the problem that I'm missing?

Comment: I checked out the sandbox, it has some weird import resolution errors, so the full application did not start properly, but I edited my answer anyways to remove what I accidentally copy pasted and was not needed. I also updated the _filter function to account for `null` values. This way the type errors will go away. Please refresh the page and make sure you included all the changes in the answer.

Comment: When I add `input type="text" [formControl]="myControl" />` to the html template I'm getting the error:     "Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)"....I imported it in the TS file....is there more I have to add to the code? I just copy pasted yours exactly.

Comment: Please import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `AppModule`. Add it to the `imports` array.

Comment: It works kind of! Thank you so much! Only thing I have left to figure out, is how to make all the countries appear first, THEN when you type it filters them out. Right now it doesn't render anything unless I type something in first. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Since you're making the call to getAllCountries at the top of the ngOnInit it may haven not (likely didn't) get response by the time the startsWith forces the _filter to run for the first time.  Couple of options to fix it, basically use combineLatest to combine multiple observables and take the latest value from each then subscribe to the output of that new combined observable stream or use resolver in routes to block component load until data is loaded (get via route snapshot) or use await to delay the ngOnInit processing on the line that fetches countries.

Comment: Curious if ran into a problem with the pipe solution I gave below too or just looking for cleaner options :)

Comment: I updated my answer. I used combineLatest to bring the two event sources together