# How do you use form input to filter objects inside an Observable array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How do I use the form input above these flags to filter the flags beneath?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s2ujmr?file=src/app/country-card/country-card.component.html

---

I thought I could use the filter function inside a pipe like this:

```
  searchFilterCountries(searchTerm: string){
    this.countries$.pipe(filter((country: any) => country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())))
  }
```

and put the input in the html template like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="searchFilterCountries($event.target.value)"/>
```

so that the filter function would fire every time theres an input, narrowing down the list of countries on display.

This doesn't work however. If this method should work, please explain what I did wrong.

---

After DAYS of google searching and reading SO posts I came up with

**home.component.html**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="myControl" />
  <app-country-card *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" [country]="country"></app-country-card>
</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent {
  allCountries: Country[] = [];
  countries$!: Observable<Country[]>;
  myControl = new FormControl('');
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService
      .getAllCountries().subscribe(countries => this.allCountries = countries);

    this.countries$ = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(searchTerm => this._filter(searchTerm))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string | null): Country[] {
    if (value === null) {
      return this.allCountries;
    }
    const filterValue = value?.toLowerCase();

    return this.allCountries.filter(country => country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work either. The page remains blank and no flags are loaded/rendered until something is typed. I need all the results to render, THEN be able to filter them.

---

I'm new to Angular and this has been so much more difficult than I anticipated. I've spent days trying to make this work and can't afford any more time. I'm desperate for help. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Please check the latest edits in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75001758/1440005). That should get you going in the right direction. Check it thoroughly, line by line, compare it with what you currently have. You seem to be asking so many questions on SO that you loose track of them. I would advise you to stop doing that.

Answer (score 1):

In the first piece of code you create a pipeline (a piped observable), but you do anything with it. It's not returned and you don't subscribe to it. You have to `.subscribe()` to an `Observable`, else it won't do anything.

Also, if you feel the need to declare a parameter as `any`, as you did in  `this.countries$.pipe(filter((country: any) => ...`, you are usually doing something wrong. Please take a look at the docs for [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter). It's not filtering elements of an array, as `[].filter(...)` does and as you use it.

Your second approach is more servicable. Your mistake here is, that you only filter, when the search term changes. You *don't* filter again if the data is loaded. You need to react to both events: data being loaded and search term changing. You could do this with the [`combineLatest`-operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest):

```
// requests & emits all countries
const loadCountries$ = this.apiService.getAllCountries().pipe(
  tap((countries) => this.allCountries = countries)
);

// emits the search term when the user types, always starts with ''
const searchTerm$ = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith('')
);

// whenever either loadCountries$ or searchTerm$ emits
// (but only after each emitted at least once)
// applies a filter-function and emits the filtered countries.
this.countries$ = combineLatest(loadCountries$, searchTerm$).pipe(
  map(([countries, searchTerm]) => this.filter(countries, searchTerm)),
);
```

Note that in this example `this.filter` was changed to take two arguments, the countries so filter *and* the search term. You might as well keep your version and use the member `this.allCountries`.

Comment: So I put this code in the ngOnInit? Then it will work? What do you mean by "keep your version and use the member this.allCountries"? Do I delete my code and replace it with yours or do I just add your code to what I already have?

Comment: Also, in my first code attempt, is it possible to make it work if I add a subscription? The first method is ideally how I would like to accomplish this because it's what I'm most used to from other frameworks. I thought maybe I was using the "(input)" event property wrong or some syntax thing.

Comment: @EricAndre Sounds like you need some more experience with rxjs first. I'd like you to understand what this code does, not to blindly copy and paste it somewhere. See my update on your first version. I believe you were confusing the `filter`-operator from rxjs with the `filter`-method of arrays. Those are not the same (well, in a sense they are, but not as you are using it)

Comment: I understand the concept of combinedLatest. When you have more than one Observable and one of them emits a value, the other Observables send their values along with it. I just don't understand how to make the initial render an observable to update along with the text input.

Comment: @EricAndre Yes, you can describe it that way. I've added some comments in the code, hope it's clearer now? That's exactyl how the initial render is controlled by an observable and updates if the search term changes.